# How can I share a variable across classes in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I have a variable named `sum`, which is the sum of the values inside multiple text boxes.

I have a button that creates the text boxes, where the value of each text box is added to `sum`, as long as the text box has a value inside it.

I then have another button that creates a label, and I want the `label.Text` value to be equal to `sum`.

Even after making the variable public, and both classes public, the `label.Text` value is always 0.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form

Dim counter As Integer = 1
Dim locationy As Integer = 169
Public sum As Integer = 0

Public Sub btn_New_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_New.Click

    Dim tBox_NewPrice As New TextBox
    tBox_NewPrice.Name = "tBox_NewPrice" & counter
    tBox_NewPrice.Size = New Size(74, 20)
    tBox_NewPrice.Location = New Point(207, locationy)
    Me.Controls.Add(tBox_NewPrice)

    counter = counter + 1
    locationy = locationy + 31

    If tBox_NewPrice.Text <> "" Then
        sum = sum + tBox_NewPrice.Text
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub btn_submit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_submit.Click
    Dim Label As New Label
    Label.Name = "label1"
    Label.Size = New Size(50, 50)
    Label.Location = New Point(20, 20)
    Me.Controls.Add(Label)
    Me.Refresh()
    Label.Text = sum

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You did not show the salient part - how those other things try to get the value, but I suspect it is a different instance

Comment: Set `Option Strict On` in the project or write it on the top of the code file. Compiler will save you a lot of debugging time then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this type of situation (trying to discern why a method is not doing what I'm expecting), I find that if I write down exactly what each line of the code is actually doing, rather than what I am expecting I can find causes of issues.  You have two event handler methods :

the add event handler does this logic:

1. Create a New textbox
2. Names it
3. Gives it a Size/Position
4. Adds it to the form's control collection
5. Adds its text property to the value in sum

then the submit event handler does this

1. Creates a new label
2. Names it
3. Gives it a Size/Position
4. Adds it to the form's control collection
5. sets its text to the value of sum

What's never done is "read from the textboxes' text property" after they are added to the form, and the user is allowed to use them.  Basically you're never collecting the value from the user, only checking the property immediately after adding them to the form. Aditionally, you're not pre-populating the text property with a value, so that at that point in time, it's an empty string.

The submit event handler needs to go about collecting the values from the entered textboxes in some fashion. Since the textboxes are dynamically added to the form with every add event handler submission, then something like this at the top of the Submit Event needs to be ran:

```
sum = 0 
For each ctrl As Control in me.Controls 
  If TypeOf ctrl Is Textbox Then 
    dim txt As Textbox = DirectCast(ctrl, Textbox)
    dim i as Integer =0 
    If Integer.TryParse(txt.Text, i) Then 
       Sum = Sum + i 
    End If 
  End If 
Next
```

What's happening is that we're walking the control collection, and looking for textboxes. And when we find one, if it's TEXT property contains an integer value, we're converting the string to an integer, and adding it to sum.

Comment: Instead of "walking" all controls and checking for the type(where form can contain other textboxes), save created textbox instances in the collection and operate on that collection without extra `if..else` statements

Comment: You can also save the `TypeOf` check and the cast by using:  `For Each ctrl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)`